# tkinter combobox border style is not working anymore

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I have a tkinter app that has multiple combo boxes and at the bottom also a Text widget. In the beginning, I used the style method in order to change the Combobox look but then I had to use a canvas in order to put text over the picture background and for some reason, my comboxes are now not changing their style anymore and are staying plain. here is a part of my code with only one combo box since the whole code is long but the concept i think should be applied the same:

```
roo = Tk()
roo.title('Shift Request')
roo.geometry('600x450')
dir_path_main_bg = os.path.join(dir_path, r"JUSTT BG For Main Window.png")
picture = PhotoImage(file=dir_path_main_bg, master=roo)
bg = Label(roo, image=picture)
bg.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# Changing the combobox menu style.
roo.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.selectBackground', '#30D5C8') # change highlight color
roo.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.selectForeground', 'white') # change text color
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('TCombobox', background='#30D5C8') # Create a border around the combobox button.
style.map('TCombobox', foreground=[('hover', 'black')], background=[('hover', '#30D5C8')]) # style the combobox when
                                                                                               # it's beeing hovered on.

# Creating a canvas for the main window menu to choose your shifts.
main_menu_canvas = Canvas(roo, width=500, height=450, highlightbackground='#30D5C8', highlightcolor='#30D5C8')
main_menu_canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
main_menu_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=picture, anchor='nw')

# A function to stop the highlighting when choosing a value.
def defocus(event):
    event.widget.master.focus_set()

# Second drop-down menu.
chosen2 = tk.StringVar(value='Shift Starting Hour')
vyber2 = ttk.Combobox(roo, textvariable=chosen2, state='readonly')
vyber2['values'] = start_shift
vyber2.bind("<FocusIn>", defocus)
vyber2.place(relx=0.27, rely=0.16, relwidth=0.45, relheight=0.09)
vyber2.config(font=('calibri', '13'))

# Changing the combobox menu style.
roo.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.selectBackground', '#30D5C8') # change highlight color
roo.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.selectForeground', 'white') # change text color
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('TCombobox', background='#30D5C8') # Create a border around the combobox button.
style.map('TCombobox', foreground=[('hover', 'black')], background=[('hover', '#30D5C8')]) # style the combobox when
#                                                                                               # it's beeing hovered on.

# Creating the text box to write notes.
default_val = tk.StringVar(value='Notes...').get()
text_box = Text(main_menu_canvas, width=45, height=6, font=('calibri','13'))
text_box.insert(INSERT, default_val)
text_box.config(highlightthickness=0.5, highlightbackground='#30D5C8', highlightcolor='#30D5C8')
main_menu_canvas.create_window(300, 336, window=text_box)

roo.mainloop()
```

My desired result is to make it look like how it was before. The first screenshot is the way it looks now and the second screenshot it's how it was before the text addition.

[image]

[image]

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: The 'alt' and 'clam' themes allow more customization. Try 
style.theme_use("alt")

Comment: I tried those but no luck with the border lines. do you know if i need to change/add a prameter in order to get a colored thin border?